# How can i get the contents of the two ids using an onclick event

Tags: html

```
<button type='text' value="{{ ursx.id }}" title="{{ ursx.get_username }}" onclick="getCredentials(event)" id="take" class="take">
    <div class="user"  id="user">
     {{ ursx.get_full_name }}
```

{#        #}

```
     console.log(id_1 + ' ' + id_2);

});
```

This is the onclick event

```
$('.take').click(function(){
        var id_1 = $('.take').val();
        var id_2 = $('.user').val();

     console.log(id_1 + ' ' + id_2);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.user` class has no `value` attribute, as it's a `<div>` element.

As such, instead of **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**, you're looking for **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** for `id_2`:

```js
$('.take').click(function() {
  var id_1 = $('.take').val();
  var id_2 = $('.user').html();
  console.log(id_1 + ' ' + id_2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type='text' value="one" id="take" class="take">
<div class="user" id="user">two</div>
```